# App Store Distribution Certificate - rename Certificate common name

Tags: ios, macos, certificate, keychain

I have 2 AppStore Distribution Certificates from 2 accounts having the same name.
Is there a way to rename Certificate's common name when it's already created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not rename the certificate without invalidating it. The common name is one of the factors that is authenticated with Apple and if you could change it then your information would not match Apple's information and you would get signing errors.